Logs out of the page after logging via API in Cypress with Cucumber
I gets log out in the UI after logging via API session. I used a custom command for the login and reuse it in one of my step definitions inside beforeEach hook. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but it's not working as expected.
//command.js
const platform = Cypress.env("platform");
Cypress.Commands.add("loginViaAPI", (user, pass) => {
  cy.session([user, pass], () => {
      cy.request({
          method: "POST",
          url:  "/login",
          body: {
              username: user,
              password: pass
          }
      }).then(res => {
          expect(res.status).to.eq(200)
          window.localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(res.body))
      })
  },
      {
          validate() {
              cy.visit("/home")
          }
      }
  )
})

//Step Definition

beforeEach(function () {
  cy.loginViaAPI(platform.admin_username, platform.password);
  cy.visit(platform.host);
});

Given("...", () => {
  cy.visit("/home");
});

When("...", () => {
 *does something*
})

Then("...", () => {
 *does something*
});```


If you run your cy.loginViaAPI() command outside of the beforeEach, and instead in a Given block, is your user correctly signed in when executing the rest of the Given block?

It's worth trying cy.window() instead of window. The app runs in an iframe, so it see a different window object, which is accessed via cy.window().
.then(res => {
  cy.window().then(win => {
    expect(status)...
    win.localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(res.body)
  })
})

Also validate() runs every time cy.session() is called, so you are effectively doing
cy.visit("/home")         <-- from validate()
cy.visit(platform.host)   <-- from beforeEach()
cy.visit("/home")         <-- from Given()

You maybe want to eliminate at least the second cy.visit(platform.host), or add cy.origin() command so the it's clear the tests should run at your baseUrl.
You do have a baseUrl in cypress.config.js? It's best practice, see Common Problems.
